# What is the best practice between var and string for Roslyn compiler in C#?

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to understand what is the best way for declaring a string, to use var or string if I already know that I have a string. For example I have the following:

```
string str = "here is some text";
```

or

```
var str = "here is some text";
```

Which one is better for the compiler in order the analyzers at Roslyn to work better for switch expressions vs switch statements?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the language and tooling perspective, these are identical. Go with which one you find is easier to maintain or read.

Comment: From the compiler perspective?

Comment: @EleniS.: I guess I'm not sure what you're asking about here: the compiler treats them the same. Sure the compiler has to do extra type inference to come up with var being string, but other than that it's the same.

Comment: My question if from compiler's perspective. What kind of extra type interference does the compiler need to do with var instead of string if you know that you have a string?

Comment: It'll just look at the right hand side of the =, see it's a string, and then it knows the var is a string. Nothing fancy.